# mysqld_safe at 100% CPU

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, cpu-usage

I've seen this discussed in several places on the web, never with a clear answer.

What does `mysqld_safe` do? What would cause it to go to 100% CPU and stay there? How can I make sure it doesn't happen again?

Is there a way to at least make it run at a lower priority, so it doesn't prevent me from logging in to my server?

Currently I'm having this problem on Ubuntu 8.04, MySQL version is 5.0.51a-3ubuntu5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysqld_safe is a shell script responsible for starting MySQL itself, so if you find it eating 100% of your CPU, I recommend you report a bug to http://bugs.mysql.com/